# Will this iOS code cause memory to fill up over a sufficiently long time?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, garbage-collection

So I'm writing an iPhone app who's only purpose is to count down from a date sometime in the future. It's a static app, will be the only non-standard app used on the phone, will always be the only thing running and the phone will be constantly charging (it's literally just going to sit in a display case). The app itself is dead simple, as you can see. The only thing I'm worried about is that over time the stack will overflow. Here's the only part of the code that actually does something

```
- (void)updateTimeRemaining {
    self.dateComponents = [self.calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                       fromDate:[NSDate date]
                                         toDate:endDate options:0];
    [self.yearsRemaining setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.dateComponents.year]];
    [self.daysRemaining setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.dateComponents.day]];
    [self.secsRemaining setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.dateComponents.second]];
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateTimeRemaining) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

Everything is weekly retained except for the calendar which never changes (although this shouldn't matter because there aren't any other views in the app). I guess this is really more of a question on iOS's garbage collection. Is it going to wait for a non-existent return value or discard the methods it doesn't need after they are done executing?

Comment: There is a hazard if you have a process that never returns to the run loop, and hence the autorelease pool is never drained.  If updateTimeRemaining is being called, eg, from a timer tick then the pool should be drained after every tick.  If it's being managed some other way then maybe not.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll implement the timer suggestion below and that should solve my problem, cheers.

Comment: I didn't catch that you were doing essentially a recursive call at the end, for the timing.  While that *probably* is safe (I'm *fairly sure* that you get an async, non-stacked invocation when you use a non-zero delay), using a repeating timer is better from several standpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure about the code you proposed. In general I find using `performSelector: afterDelay:` to be bad form.

Have you considered using `+ (NSTimer *)timerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds invocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation repeats:(BOOL)repeats` instead? I would imagine it to be much more reliable. It should also return back to the run loop and let processes like garbage collection occur naturally.

It's well-documented by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

Comment: Hey Sam, if you don't mind could you check the box that says that my answer closes your question? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, hand't actually implemented it, there you go